# How can you monitor a variable during a Matlab loop without printing it?

Tags: matlab, loops, monitoring

I am running a loop, in which variables are calculated. It would be useful to be able to see the current values of these variables. It is not useful to print them, because other parts of the loop are printing a lot of text. Also, on the `Workspace` tab, the values do not display until the end of the loop.

Is there a way to monitor those variables, f.i. by printing them into a window?

Comment: Does the loop take a _long_ time? Do you want to do this to troubleshoot or just to have a look? You can use the debugger if it's troubleshooting. Do you want to print it to something else than the console?

Comment: Yes, the loop takes a long time and I want to do this to troubleshoot. Maybe the solution would then be to print it to a figure window.

Comment: If it's slow, and you're trying to speed it up, you should [profile your code using the profiler](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) . `profile on` then execute your stuff, `profile off` and `profile viewer` or somethign like that. If it's just taking a long time and you don't want to make it faster, realize that any checks you add to your loops will make it slower. You could also stick something like `if(mod(ii, 1000)==0) disp('stuff to display every 1000 iterations'); end`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can create a figure with a [`text`](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/text.html) object and update its `'string'` property according to the desired variable:

```
h = text(.5, .5, ''); %// create text object
for n = 1:1000
    v = n^2; %// loop computations here. Variable `v` is to be displayed
    set(h, 'string', ['Value: ' num2str(v)]);
    drawnow %// you may need this for immediate updating
end
```

For greater speed, you can either update only every `S` iterations:

```
h = text(.5, .5, ''); %// create text object
S = 10; %// update period
for n = 1:1000
    v = n^2; %// loop computations here. Variable `v` is to be displayed
    if ~mod(n,S) %// update only at iterations S, 2*S, 3*S, ...
        set(h, 'string', ['Value: ' num2str(v)]);
        drawnow %// you may need this for immediate updating
    end
end
```

or use `drawnow('limitrate')` as noted by @Edric:

```
h = text(.5, .5, ''); %// create text object
for n = 1:1000
    v = n^2; %// loop computations here. Variable `v` is to be displayed
    set(h, 'string', ['Value: ' num2str(v)]);
    drawnow('limitrate')
end
```

Comment: This is a nice solution assuming that this is a long loop, and the value she/he wants to look at is updated less than one time per second. Otherwise it would make the loop considerably slower (I would guess)...?

Comment: @StewieGriffin Yes, this would surely slow the loop down. If the OP only wants to check the variable every `S` iterations they can use `mod` in an `ìf` branch. I'll update with that

Comment: IMHO, drawing goes in the category of super clever stuff you could but probably shouldn't do. if you only do it every x iterations, then it may be reasonable.

Comment: @StewieGriffin Hahaha. _Touché_

Comment: How about `drawnow('limitrate')`

Comment: Good idea! I didn't know about that form of `drawnow`

Comment: If the calculation in the loop is the limiting factor and not the number of iterations, Then putting the values in the title of a `waitbar` is also a good option.